# Visualforce tab panel are not shown how i add it to all page, header will be same content will change

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Visualforce tab panel are not shown how I add it to all page, header will be same content will change

Let's start from the first step i create a Visualforce tab on this tab I add one VF page which has three inner tabs(using TabPanel), on click on each tab their is a new button when we click on that a new VF page(on which we add something and we also have saved & cancel button) will be open but my problem is that on this page my tabs are not shown and on cancel it come to the first page there also tab panel are not shown.

**Tab Panel:**

```
<apex:page standardController="BusterSetting__c" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
    <!-- Define Tab panel .css styles -->
    <style>
    .activeTab {background-color: #236FBD; color:white; background-image:none}
    .inactiveTab { background-color: lightgrey; color:black; background-image:none}
</style>

<!-- Create Tab panel -->
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name1" id="BusterSettingsTabPanel"
    tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">
    <apex:tab label="Find Duplicate Layout" name="name1" id="tabOne">
    <apex:include pageName="FindDuplicatePageLayout"/>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Result Page Layout" name="name2" id="tabTwo">
     <apex:include pageName="ResultPageLayout"/>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Type Ahead" name="name3" id="tabThree">
    content for tab Three
    </apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

**Here is a new Button:**

**Click on New this vf will be shown:**

```
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Filter Name" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Buster Job Name:"></apex:outputLabel>
                        <apex:inputText title="Buster Job Name" value="{!saveJobName}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                 </apex:pageBlockSection> 

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Standard or Custom Object" columns="2" collapsible="false">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="Object:"/> 
                        <apex:actionRegion >      
                            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!objNames}"/>
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getObjectFields}" rerender="myFields"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:actionRegion>                         
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:outputPanel id="myFields"> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Fields" collapsible="false">
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem > 
                        <c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Fields"
                        leftOption="{!allFields}" 
                        rightLabel="Selected Fields"
                        rightOption="{!selectedFields}"
                        size="14" width="150px" />  
                    </apex:pageblocksectionItem>       
            </apex:pageblocksection>
                </apex:outputpanel>

            <apex:pageblockButtons location="top">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save & New" action="{!saveAndNew}" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" immediate="true"/>
            </apex:pageblockButtons> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```